# Blender 3.5 simulation: colliding points

Tags: geometry-nodes, collision, simulation-nodes

Different people showed ways to collide points with faces of a geometry (external collisions), when using simulation nodes in Blender 3.5. I couldn't find a neat way to collide points with each other (internal collisions). I've tried different kind of node trees, but unfortunately without any succes.

Is it even possible to collide points or to mimic this?

My goal is to start with a lineair momentum, in which point m1 collides with point m2. After collision, the velocity of point m1 is zero and point m2 is moving with the same (or a little less) velocity as m1 before collision:

[image]

Comment: I had just miss read your question so my answer wasn't on the point (if I may). But I made some progress that I will post soon...Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqHOvP59L0o&t=976s), we can effectively
do some "externals collisions" but here we have to get rid of the radius of detection... We can't or there is no more collision. But we can disable the effects of the collision under certain conditions with a `Switch`. For your example I used `Compare` nodes to be sure if the target point is on path of the moving one.

[image]

If the the target move a little bit out of this path the switch is on: there is no more collision affecting the points regardless of the radius of detection.

[image]

And so it act like points.
This set up need to be improved and simplified but you get the general ideas...

[image]

PS: As this configuration works only with a static target, it will be great to add all the moving ones1. One more condition have to be added: knowing if the lines that support the points with the same direction of their velocity vectors intersects...

Comment: Tnx a lot! Very kind :-) I will check your answer later today. If I make any progress I'll let you know.

Comment: @EwSa
 I have make some progress on the moving points thanks to Markus von Broady with the intersecting lines here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283087/how-to-determine-if-lines-intersects